# binary classification using SVM Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, cross-validation

I am trying to do binary classification using SVM which available in Matlab.
I have about 32000 data. My data has 32 inputs or predictors (32-bit binary). And the output is either 0 or 1. Like below:

```
         <Inputs>                <Output>
```

11101110111011101011110111010111   0

10101101101111100001011011100010   1

10111011100110001001010100000110   0

:

:

until 32000 input-output pairs.

I increment the number of data by 1000 and use hold-out (10%) method for testing.

So, the first data 1000, the training set is 900 and test set is 100.

Subsequent data 2000, the training set is 1800 and test set is 200.

until.....

last data 32000, the training set is 28800 and test set is 3200.

I was expecting that, when I increase the number of training data, the prediction accuracy increases as well. BUT it was not. The prediction accuracy just stayed flat at about 60%.

My guess is SVM do not understand my input data, thus not able to perform classification properly. Do I need to do some pre-processing/transformation on my input data? if yes, what kind of pre-processing should I perform?

Thanks

SVM newbie.

----update: here is my code in Matlab---------
In .csv file, the first 32 columns is the input and the last column is the output.

```
% Binary Classification

clc;
clear;

% Read the input file
% Data in the file must be in the format <32-bit input> <1-bit output>
M = dlmread('Data_32000.csv');
[row_M,col_M]=size(M);


%Divide training into many subsets - different training sizes
inc = 1000;
set = row_M/inc;
label{:}=zeros;
score{:}=zeros;
L{:}=zeros;
for i=1:set
% Partition the data into training and test sets. Hold out 10% of the data for testing.
rng(10);                                % For reproducibility of holdout function
cvp = cvpartition(inc*i,'Holdout',0.1);
idxTrn = training(cvp);                 % Training set indices
idxTest = test(cvp);                    % Test set indices

% Redefine training set based on random hold-out
X_train = M(idxTrn,1:col_M-1);
Y_train = M(idxTrn,col_M);

% Redefine test set based on random hold-out
X_test = M(idxTest,1:col_M-1);
Y_test = M(idxTest,col_M);

% Train an SVM classifier using the radial basis kernel. Let the software find a scale value for the kernel function.
SVMModel = fitcsvm(X_train,Y_train,'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','RBF','KernelScale','auto');

% Display the properties of SVM model
classOrder = SVMModel.ClassNames;
sv = SVMModel.SupportVectors;

% Predict the out-of-sample labels and the score
[label{i},score{i}] = predict(SVMModel,X_test); 

% Test sample classification error of SVM classifiers
L{i} = loss(SVMModel,X_test,Y_test);
end
```

Comment: Please provide the code you used to train your SVM and perform the prediction.  It is impossible to determine why your accuracy is not improving without actually seeing what you have done.

Comment: Hello Rayryeng, thanks for your comment. I have updated with Matlab code.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like you enabled standardization as part of your SVM.  Given that you have binary data, that is usually a bad idea.  See this post on Cross Validated for more details: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59392/should-you-ever-standardise-binary-variables.  Also, looking at your data now, each bit would be a feature and there is not enough variance for each feature to be discriminatory for classification. One thing I can suggest is to maybe take your binary string and break it up into separate `N`-bit strings, convert them to some other base representation and train.

Comment: Hi, I have tried as what you suggested:
1) coupled two bits and convert them to decimal. So from 32 bits, I made into 16 of 2-bit strings and converted to decimal.
2) 8 of 4-bit strings
Both still give me prediction accuracy of ~70 for all the training sets. I have also tried to convert 0 in 32-bit input to -1. But still, does not work. In your comment, you mentioned about variance. Do we have any rules how much variance should we have to differentiate between each feature from other sets of input?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry. I think it's time you go ask on Cross Validated. http://stats.stackexchange.com